# Using Rvest command for an html table

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I am trying to get the table located in the following URL:
https://wallethub.com/edu/most-innovative-states/31890/

I used following code (I used SelectorGadget as well to get CSS), but it is not working. Is it an special case or is there another code that I can use?:

```
page <- read_html("https://wallethub.com/edu/most-innovative-states/31890/")
table <- page %>%
  html_node(xpath = "/html/body/div[2]/main/div/div[1]/article/div[3]/div[1]/div[6]/table/thead/tr/th[3]") %>%
  html_table()
table
head(table)
```

Comment: In addition to the answer given, you could stay with xpath and go with something like: page %>% html_node(xpath = "//table") %>% html_table()

Comment: This deserves to be a second answer, since some might use xpath and the original was in xpath.

Comment: I agree, Is there a way to do so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just selecting on `table` worked for me:

```
page %>% 
  html_node("table") %>% 
  html_table()
```

Comment: You're welcome, if it was helpful [this is the next step](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).